# Cannot get filter to execute in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, haml, angular-filters

I have an ng-repeat of events, each of which has a date. I want to allow the user to filter out all events not between two dates. I figured I'd make a custom filter for this.

I'm using HAML, so here's how my HTML looks:

```
%tr{'ng-repeat' => 'event in events | filter:dateRange | event.name'}
```

Okay so now my filter looks like this right now:

```
filters.filter('dateRange', function() {
  return function(){
    var a = 'a';
    return a;
  };
});
```

Obviously my filter doesn't really do anything yet, but when I set a breakpoint on var a, or on return a, it never is reached. I want to do this so I can see the context at this point and then write the filter. I know it reaches the filter because when I set a breakpoint on filters.filter, it does reach it. Why does it not enter the function and execute anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ng-repeat value should look like

```
%tr{'ng-repeat' => 'event in events | dateRange: event.name'}
```

when using a filter you supply the filter name, and optionally if you have arguments to your filter you follow with a colon and then the expression.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass as parameter an variable that represents your text.
For example:

```
myApp.filter('myfilter',function(){
    return function(txt){
      return txt = 'a'; 
   }
})
```

:)

Comment: So I just added that, but I still can't get a breakpoint to be hit on that return statement.